# Create a widget in wordpress to display both most recent and most popular posts

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, posts

I'm building a function to display my most recent posts in WordPress and I'd like to know how to return some of them:

here's my code so far:

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

I copied a suggestion based on an idea of how to display the most recent posts without a plugin. So far so good, except that I need to return something in order to create a small widget to switch between most recent and most popular. The most popular widget was slightly easier like:

```
function get_recent_posts($count){
    $args = [
        'numberposts' => $count,
        'offset' => 0,
        'category' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'include' => '',
        'exclude' => '',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' =>'',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    ];

    return wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
}
```

And that's the part where I can switch between them:

```
function get_blog_posts($count , $type='recent'){

    if($type=='recent'){

        $posts = get_recent_posts($count);
    } else {
        $posts = wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
    }
    var_dump($posts);
    die();
    return $posts;
}
```

As I said, I'm trying to build it so, at the moment I'm dumping my array to see if they work like I aspect. If I switch to popular I will obtain a NULL value, but if I try to return my function with

```
return function wpb_set_post_views($postID);
```

I forgot to mention that I will call my function in my template in this way:

```
<?php if($blog_posts = get_blog_posts( wp_kses_post($instance['posts_type']) )): 

        foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post) : 

            ?>
            <a class="blog-archive-sidebar-feed" href="<?=get_permalink($blog_post['ID'])?>">
                <span class="blog-archive-title"><?=$blog_post['post_title']?></span>
                <p class="blog-archive-date"><?=date('F d, Y' , strtotime($blog_post['post_date']))?></p>
            </a>


        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Anyway, nothing will happen.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

First, the `wpb_set_post_views()` function doesn't return anything because there is no `return` statement in it, so it is perfectly normale that `return wpb_set_post_views($postID);` doesn't return anything.

Secondly, wpb_set_post_views() is meant to update the post meta variable that store the nb of view of a specified post, not to return the list of most viewed post.

You will need to create such a function (let's say `get_most_viewed_posts($count);` for exemple), then call it inside your `get_blog_posts()` function insead of `wpb_set_post_views()`.

Comment: Do you have any example or something to start from?

Comment: Yes, you need to keep both, basically a good practice is to keep things simple : one functionnality = 1 function. i helps keep things clear and 'easily' maintainable. You can check the Wordpress documentation for get_posts() method (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) which can be used to request posts from database with a lot of possibilities using parameters (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)